# how to find the value of constant of differential equation using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
DSolve[y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 0, y[x], x]

{{y[x] -> E^(-2 x) C[1]}}
```

how can I find the value of C[1] using Solve command with initial condition y[0]==1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mathematica solving differential equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020606/mathematica-solving-differential-equations)

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly specify your initial condition into the `DSolve` function? You can do that symbolically, no need for a numerical value:

```
In[]= DSolve[{y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 0, y[a1] == C1}, y[x], x]

Out[]= {{y[x] -> C1 E^(2 a1 - 2 x)}}
```

MMA official doc: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html